# C++ : Create unique random distributions 1000 times with no repeated numbers in any distribution

Tags: c++, random, range, unique, distribution

**Problem:**

I have a number range of 1 to 20,000. I would like to sample a uniform distribution of 8 different numbers from the range, 1000 times. Each distribution should have no repeated numbers. Also every distribution among the 1000 distributions must be unique (after doing alphabetical sort of all obtained distributions, no two distributions should be technically the same number sequence).

**What I did:**

I came across the `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>` in C++ 11 standard. So tried this following code to test its uniqueness over different ranges.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(int, char*[]) {
    const int range_from  = 0;
    const int range_to    = 20000;
    std::random_device                  rand_dev;
    std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distr(range_from, range_to);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){ //Iteration for maximum distributions

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) //Iteration for random distribution generation
            std::cout << distr(generator) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output obtained for different attempts**

```
Attempt 1:      Attempt 2:

16102           6656
540             10316
8718            12251
18059           1254
10976           3982
18391           12857
14748           9253
12137           3335
```

**Some facts:**

The output appears unique based on the two attempts. I also realize the fact that there can be 20,000C8 = 20,000!/(8!x19,992!) such possible distributions which can be unique (no same numbers in each distribution and no repetition of distributions when we do an alphabetical sort).

**My Question:**

Can this code really do what I intend to do in its current form? Or should I do some expensive verification process like doing an alphabetical sort of each distribution and record each each of them in an `std::vector` and check whether the distribution is already there?

The latter process is very expensive and takes huge computational time. Would you suggest any alternative/better ways of doing it?

Comment: You severely underestimate the number of distributions, it is on the other of 20000 choose 8 or 6.3403226e+29.  The chance of getting identical distributions is vanishingly small.  Getting a repeated number is reasonably possible, and you may want to check for that.

Comment: Thanks for this intuition max. So should I take it that I have to still do some verification process to ensure that the distributions are perfect ?

Comment: @Max The OP considers `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` to be the same thing which changes the math.

Comment: Thank you NathanOliver. You got my question perfectly.

Comment: @NathanOliver 20000C8/8! (to ignore order) is still 10^25 ish.

Comment: @Max I think you are right about the math. I realize that I under-estimated the possibilities of different unique distributions. I now believe there can be much more than 2,500 of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the 1000 sets of 8 random number to be unique then you can generate all values you want, randomize them, and then take the first 8000 values from the randomized set as your 1000 sets of 8 random numbers.

```
int main()
{
    const int range_from  = 0;
    const int range_to    = 20000;
    std::vector<int> values(range_to - range_from);

    std::generate(values.begin(), values.end(), [value = range_from]() mutable { return value++; });  
    // values now has 0 to 20000                                                                                            
    std::shuffle(values.begin(), values.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    // now it is a random order

    values.resize(8000);
    // now we have the 8000 random numbers in the range 0 to 20000
}
```

This isn't too wasteful in this case but if your range gets large enough and the number of sets you wants is small enough you might want to chose a different solution.  Otherwise you would wind up wasting a lot of space.

Comment: Wow. This is a great thinking. Exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Comment: This removes the possibility of any duplicate number *anywhere*, which I don't believe is what the OP specified.

Comment: @Max You're right.  I though that was what the OP needed.  The way their question is worded `1,2,3` and `1,2,4` should be okay, they just wouldn't want a `2,3,1` or `2,4,1` showing up.

Comment: @ArunKumar Please see the above comments.  This may be more unique then you really need.

Comment: "[after sort] no two distributions should be technically the same number sequence" indicates that the set of 8 can't be the same, which is extremely unlikely.  This solution will satisfy the requirements, but reduce the solution space quite a bit.  20000 choose 8000 is still astronomical so may be sufficient.

Comment: [Fisher-Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) can be used to save some memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver you understood my question perfectly. Your answer perfectly does what I wanted to do. You are correct that I am okay with `1,2,3` and `1,2,4` but I don't want `1,2,3` and other arrangements of the same sequence like `3,2,1` or `2,1,3` or `3,1,2`. Nor do I want repeated numbers in a sequence like `1,3,7,3` or `4,9,2,4,4`. It is because I care more about the unique numbers in the distribution rather than the permutation of them.